# Why is Guid.ToString returning capitalised string in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net

I have encountered some weird/unexpected behaviour in which `Guid.ToString()` in a Linq expression returns a different result than `Guid.ToString()` in a foreach loop.

**What the method is doing**:

The method in question is simply taking an object and then creates a new view-model from the original object. The company I work for has decided that Guid's will not be allowed on view-models, due to one of our older JSON serializers having an bug in which Guid's were not serialized correctly.

**The problem/unexpected result**:

While debugging/testing my method I found that the Linq expression I created was returning a strange result. When converting my Guid to its string representation, the result was being automatically capitalised. I didn't believe that it was the Linq expression at first but once I had converted the logic into a foreach loop I got a lower-cased string representation of my Guid.

**Example code**:

Please note that the property types for lookupList (ID1, ID2, ID3) are all of type Guid and the properties on NewClass are all of type string.

Linq expression:

```
List<NewClass> returnList = lookupList.Select(i => new NewClass {
                   Property1 = i.ID1.ToString(),
                   Property2 = i.ID2.ToString(),
                   Property3 = i.ID3.ToString(),
                   .....
                }).ToList();
```

Returns:

```
{
    Property1=7081C549-64D6-458E-A693-0D2C9C47D183
    Property2=06DD6A59-D339-4E15-89EA-48803DBA271E
    Property3=9A876EDD-3B79-C27E-1680-E0820A0CD6EC
}
```

Foreach loop:

```
var returnList = new List<NewClass>();

foreach (var item in lookupList)
{
    returnList.Add(new NewClass
    {
        Property1 = item.ID1.ToString(),
        Property2 = item.ID2.ToString(),
        Property3 = item.ID3.ToString(),
        .....
    });
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    Property1=7081c549-64d6-458e-a693-0d2c9c47d183
    Property2=06dd6a59-d339-4e15-89ea-48803dba271e
    Property3=9a876edd-3b79-c27e-1680-e0820a0cd6ec
}
```

**The question**:

Why is this happening and is this expected behaviour? I would expect both the Linq expression and the foreach loop to return the same result when `.ToString()` is applied to my Guid but somehow it is not. I have also checked that there are no `.ToString()` overrides in either class.

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

The `lookupList` has been handled by a `.ToList()` before it hits my method. `LookupList` is of type `List<t>` where `t` is a custom business entity which has additional properties that the database does not have. Apologies, I did not make this clear in my original question.

Comment: Is there a database involved? Because the first call might be executed in context of your sql server, while the second one most certainly executes in context of the clr. It depends on what `lookupList` really is.

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue in .Net 4.0

Comment: A database is involved but the result has been ToList'ed before it hits my method. LookupList is List<t> where t is a custom business entity which looks like the database table but has some additional properties on it.

Comment: I suggest that you create [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) so we can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - lowercase string representation is always returned. From what I see from the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,3b51cd20b65c9110,references), `Guid.ToString()` uses `HexToChar(int a)` method that simply adds `0x61` (a lower-case char value `a`) to convert hexadecimal values `A-F` to character.
Make sure you aren't missing anything.

Comment: @Silvermind I'll get that example for you ASAP. I'll try and see if I can replicate it outside of my current solution. Sergey I will have a look at the link you provided.

Comment: It's obvious that it's not ToString() method but the source where this guids (with capitalized latters) came from is in charge of what happens

Comment: Can you show the class `T` of `List<T> lookupList` (or, what are the types of the `ID` properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `lookupList` is a IQueryable object, so that you are using `LINQ to SQL`, and not `LINQ to object`, then the two queries are not the same.

```
lookupList.Select(i => new NewClass { Property1 = i.ID1.ToString(), etc..
```

Will perform a SQL SELECT, the result will depend on your DBMS. My guess is that the ToString will be translate to something like `CAST(Property1, varchar)`

Whereas this query:

```
foreach (var item in lookupList)
{
    returnList.Add(new NewClass { Property1 = item.ID1.ToString(), etc..
```

will first does a select in your database, and then calling ToString on it. So the method triggered is the ToString method of the C# object GUID.

Try this for example :

```
List<NewClass> returnList = lookupList.ToList().Select(i => new NewClass {
               Property1 = i.ID1.ToString(),
               Property2 = i.ID2.ToString(),
               Property3 = i.ID3.ToString(),
               .....
            }).ToList();
```

This should return lowercase Properties.

The .ToString is not normally support in SQL, and the first query should exception. But my guess it that someone in your team read that [blog post that explain how you can create a SQL function that will map an Entity Framework call](http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/custom-function-entity-framework.html).

Interesting fact : the example function create uppercase Guid strings.

EDIT : In pure LINQ to Object, this code return lowercase strings:

```
var lookupList = new[] { new Tuple<Guid, Guid>(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()) };
var returnList = lookupList.Select(i => new
{
    Property1 = i.Item1.ToString(),
    Property2 = i.Item2.ToString(),
}).ToList();
```

We need more infos on `lookupList` object and those properties `IDx`. Are they pure C# [Guid object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Guid)?

You said that you already .ToListed your object. That will not work if your are doing it the wrong way :

**BAD**:

```
lookupList.ToList();
var returnList = lookupList.Select(i => new NewClass {
```

**GOOD**:

```
var purePOCOList = lookupList.ToList();
var returnList = purePOCOList.Select(i => new NewClass {
```

Comment: What your saying makes sense, however my lookupList has been enumerated (ToList) before it hits my method.

Comment: @MrHickle Well, if you called `ToList()` on the `lookupList` it doesn't change the `lookupList` itself. It still will contain the same query.

Comment: @Dzienny : good point, .ToList doesn't listed in place, it returns a new object.

Comment: @CyrilGandon You were spot on. I looked into my code and I saw exactly what you pointed out. I was applying .ToList() to the IQuerable but not passing the result into my method. Feel a bit stupid now for not spotting that. Thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: You should thanks @Dzienny, he spotted that first :)

Comment: @CyrilGandon I really appreciate this in-depth answer. Though, curiously, wouldn't it be more performant (and cleaner) to simply do a `i.Id.ToString().ToLower()`, since that would all be handled in a native SQL query?